# Android app recent update - back button

Tags: bug, android-app

In the update I received of the android app tonight the button in the upper left corner when inside a question has been converted into a back button whereas before it took you to a menu. Besides the fact that the back button is superfluous as devices (at least my device) have their own back button, the button takes you through every different version of the question you've seen by reloading, so you have to press it multiple times to get back to the main screen. I tagged this as a bug because I'm earnestly hoping that this is not by design.

Edit: it's not every different version of the question, as I just tested now. It happened after I answered a question. The button took me back to the question when it had no answer. I wasn't able to reproduce that, but it definitely also happens when I go to linked questions from the question page. The back button takes you back through all of the questions when there really should be a way to get back to the home screen right away.

Comment: Yes, the button should you be taking you back to the previous screen, not a question page. Re: superfluous-ness, that's part of the [Android design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) and I'd say certainly better than just having the app icon there for no reason like the previous versions did.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi so by design?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi the app icon certainly wasn't useless. It took you to a menu.

Comment: @MattSamuel the menu being highly advertised while look at drilldown content goes against the design guide, but you can still get to the menu by swiping from the left. This matches the exact behavior in GMail.

Comment: @ShadowWizard not [status-bydesign] yet since I think the top portion of this bug is actually a bug.